# How to add duplicate value to existing column in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 DECLARE @fr varchar(50)
 DECLARE @to varchar(50)

 SELECT * 
 FROM test1.dbo.duplicate 
 WHERE dbavailability >= -1 

  IF (@fr='2014-05-01' AND @to='2014-05-04')
  BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE test1.dbo.duplicate ADD DEFAULT ((5)) FOR dbavailability
  END
Database data:

 id    | tpoi | date       | dbavailability
--------------------------------------------
 1     | A    | 2014-05-01 | 5
 1     | A    | 2014-05-02 | 4
 1     | A    | 2014-05-03 | 3
 1     | A    | 2014-05-04 | -1
Expected result:

 id    | tpoi | date       | dbavailability
--------------------------------------------
 1     | A    | 2014-05-01 | -1
 1     | A    | 2014-05-02 | -1
 1     | A    | 2014-05-03 | -1
 1     | A    | 2014-05-04 | -1
```

I have this table data in date column having 1 to 4 ok and dbavailability contains 5,4,3,-1 ok now I am searching record like from date means (2014-05-01) To date(2014-05-04) records. In that records dbavailability contains -1 then the whole column dbavailability should be -1 for a particular id so how to add duplicate values to "dbavailability" column? and in my query i am using if condition but its not getting correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
 id, tpoi, "date", CASE WHEN id IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            id 
        FROM 
            test1.dbo.duplicate 
        WHERE 
            dbavailability = -1) THEN '-1' ELSE dbavailability END AS dbAvailaility
FROM test1.dbo.duplicate 
WHERE 
date BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-04'
```

Comment: Just add additional check for date range you need

Comment: 0 row affected and is it possible when i am selecting values from data table that time duplicate conversation?

Comment: If you do date check like in your code above - it is wrong

Comment: but i want to like if from to To date in bitween any one date contains -1 then all the row become -1 only for that particulat id

Comment: so here u updating database values but dont want to update the value while selecting the records that time only its become -1

Comment: ya only when i am selecting that time only not to update values

Comment: I just recreated your table, checked the code and it works as expected. Changes all dbvailability to -1 with the same id on given date range if at least on value is -1.

Comment: ya its changing the value but its upating the values i dont want to update values while searching record and displaying that time time only the values should be chang not update in database table.

Comment: It's better if you explain *why* your code solves the problem. See [answer].

Comment: is it possible or not

Comment: tell something is it possible or not?